# Script to time Loading Time of Website

Tags: javascript, performance, web, loading

I've been trying to optimize the time my site takes to load and want to make measurements to see if things are improving.

Instead of manually reloading the page and logging out the time between when the page begins to load and when it's ready I want to automate it somehow.

I've been using the command:

```
window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd- window.performance.timing.navigationStart
```

I'm quite unexperienced with writing these kinds of scripts, but is there a way to use the above command and `location.reload()` to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2):

As per the example provided here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API

```
var perfData = window.performance.timing; 
var pageLoadTime = perfData.loadEventEnd - perfData.navigationStart;
```